# Distinguish between click and binding update on checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a strange situation with a binding that needs addressing. I have a checkbox that is bound to an inherited virtual function from a base class like so:

```
Checked="CheckboxStatusChanged"
Unchecked="CheckboxStatusChanged"
```

Inside the status change, a variable "enabled" is set in MainWindow **and** a json file that is shared across machines. However, when this view is loaded on startup, the  "enabled" value is loaded from the json, and thus triggers the binding.

The issue is that the "Checked" event fires when the binding updates. For a particular purpose, I need to know when a user manually triggers the checkbox, and **not** when a binding causes its update.

I've dug into the event args and sender parameters, but with no luck. Any suggestions would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this but feel free not to except it because to each their own.

The overall problem is that you're mixing binding with events or code behind logic.  I personally don't recommend binding in the view and then to the events in code behind, although you do see it even in a lot of tutorials.  The reason is to prevent the exact issue you're having now, which is a common issue when you do.  My recommendation is that you choose to either utilize the code behind and programmatically set the states as well as handle the events or discard the events and work with binding and commands etc in the view.  I would always recommend binding or MVVM if asked that question directly so if you're willing to take the advice then that's my answer.